# How to send key/secret pair with Poloniex API?

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to write a simple script to validate that I am making an API call correctly, and then I plan to build out a more complex program from there. The error response I am receiving is:

```
{"error":"Invalid API key\/secret pair."}
```

The API documentation for what I'm working on can be found at:

https://poloniex.com/support/api/

I've just been incrementing the nonce manually to keep things simple.

My code is:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib

APIKey = "<my_API_key>"
Secret = "<my_secret>"
post_request
"command=returnBalances"
sign = hmac.new(Secret, post_request, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request("https://poloniex.com/tradingApi?   key=" + APIKey + "&sign=" + sign + "&nonce=0008"))

print ret.read()
```

Comment: The error says you have an invalid key/secret pair, so the problem is probably you have an invalid/key secret pair I guess.

Comment: Try sending the key and secret in the header, as in [this example](http://pastebin.com/8fBVpjaj), lines 44 to 51. Or just use that nice wrapper yourself, it looks handy.

Comment: The API docs say you must send the Key and Secret in the headers, you're sending them as url parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your APIKey and Secret are OK, this following version will works:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib


req={}

APIKey = "<my_API_key>"
Secret = "<my_secret>"

command="returnBalances"

req['command'] = command

req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
post_data = urllib.urlencode(req)

sign = hmac.new(Secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
#print sign
headers = {
    'Sign': sign,
    'Key': APIKey
}

ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers))
jsonRet = json.loads(ret.read())

print jsonRet
```

If you run this code with your own secret and API key and it still doesn't work.
That is sure that your APIKey or secret have typing error !! [ or APIkey is restricted to "withdraw only" or you have selected IP restriction and try to connect from an unknow IP.]

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation says:

> All calls to the trading API are sent via HTTP POST to https://poloniex.com/tradingApi and must contain the following headers:
>
> - Key - Your API key.
> - Sign - The query's POST data signed by your key's "secret" according to the HMAC-SHA512 method.
>
> Additionally, all queries must include a "nonce" POST parameter.

<del>Even though it says "headers", I think it means POST parameters.</del>

Also looking at the [reference Python implementation](http://pastebin.com/8fBVpjaj) linked by the docs, it appears that the API wants `Key` and `Sign` as headers, and `nonce` as POST parameter.

Change your request from:

```
urllib2.Request("https://poloniex.com/tradingApi?   key=" + APIKey + "&sign=" + sign + "&nonce=0008")
```

to:

```
data = urllib.urlencode({
    'nonce': '0008',
    # ...
    # insert here the other parameters you need
    # ...
})
headers = {
    'Key': APIKey,
    'Sign': sign,
}
urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', data, headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.parse
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib
import httpx

APIKey = "<my_API_key>"
Secret = "<my_secret>"

req={}
req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
req['command'] = "returnDepositAddresses"

# encoding post_data for sign calculation
encoded_post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(req).encode('utf-8')

sign = hmac.new(bytes(Secret, 'utf-8'), encoded_post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headers = {
    'Sign': sign,
    'Key': APIKey
}

with httpx.Client() as client:
    url = 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi'
    response = client.post(url, headers=headers, data=req)

data = response.json()

print(data)
```

Try this. This should work, tested.
It's necessary to encode request data (our 'req' dictionary) and then calculate sign using this encoded post data.
and I used httpx for requests, my personal flavor.

Cheers.

Comment: req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000) this nonce calculation is for one client, but if you want make same client and multiple request, my experiences result is multiply time.time()*1000000 is better than multiply with 1000.